# WSAPoll changing data in FDSET and returning an error due to WSAENOTSOCK. Am I using WSAPoll() correctly?

Tags: c++, c, winsock2

Below is the minimum code needed for using WSAPoll, not counting the initialization (`socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, etc.) or any conditionals before it. You can use the [sample server code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code) from the docs and `sock` would be `ClientSocket` as a base.

Running it, the values change per-line as per follows:

```cpp
// ...
// socket(), bind(), listen(), etc.
// sock = accept(...)
// See boilerplate linked.

SOCKET sock;          // sock = 356
FDSET set;            // Some garbled data, though should be same as below:
FD_ZERO(&set);        // fd_count = 0, fd_array = [14757395258967641292, x64]
FD_SET(sock, &set);   // fd_count = 1, fd_array = [356, 14757395258967641292 x63]
int iResult = WSAPoll(&set, 1, 1)      // iResult = -1
                      // fd_count = 1, fd_array = [262500, 14757395258967641292 x63]
int errid = WSAGetLastError();    // errid = WSAENOTSOCK (10038)

// if (iResult > 0)
// recv(), etc.
```

If I read it right, [`WSAPoll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll) is supposed to emulate [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). So, when I store `sock` into `set`, it stores it properly, but when it's passed into `WSAPoll()` however, the values change and it returns -1 with `errno` being `WSAENOTSOCK` (10038).

Now, the problem here is that `sock` is a perfectly valid file descriptor; socket. `recv()` and `send()` works just fine without any errors.
File descriptor `262500` on the other hand, not so much.

Am I polling correctly or am I somehow not casting it properly, because it doesn't look like it needs to be casted since `SOCKET` and `fd_array` are just a/an singular/array of `unsigned __int64`(s).

Comment: This code should not even compile

Comment: You need to show how `sock` was acquired and what has happened to it subsequently, for example whether it has been closed on `recv()` returning zero or -1. NB `errno` does not return the last socket error in Winsock. You need to call `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: Pretty much getting the socket is that boilerplate server code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the parameters to `select()` and `poll()/WSAPoll()`.

It's `select()` that takes an `FDSET` as a parameter. `poll()/WSApoll()` takes a `pollfd` array as a parameter.

It appears that the hyperlink in the cited Microsoft documentation, for the description of the `WSAPOLLFD` parameter, is 404-compliant. Perhaps you can find it somewhere else, or use the documentation of the Linux version, (Google keyword: `struct pollfd`).

It is also fairly likely that your compiler is yelling warning messages, and other obscenities at you; because the type of the first parameter to `WSAPoll` is obviously the wrong pointer type. If so, this is a good lesson never to ignore warning messages from a C++ compiler, even if it still compiles your program.

Comment: 404-compliant? You mean like the HTTP error code?

Comment: Yes, a little Intertubes humor. The link is compliant with the HTTP 404 status code.

Comment: What does Intertubes mean?

Comment: That's another bit of Internet humor. Your Google keyword is "series of tubes".

Comment: See [WSAPOLLFD structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vstudio/ms740094(v=vs.90)).  But, FWIW, [`WSAPoll()` is buggy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/18769abd-fca0-4d3c-9884-1a38ce27ae90/wsapoll-and-nonblocking-connects-to-nonexistent-ports?forum=wsk) and should not be used at all (even Microsoft says so!).